# Fetching data from Firebase is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from Firebase database into an dictionary, but the value I'm getting is nil! I've tried to restructure my database, as well observe(.value...) and observe(.childAdded...), but without any luck.

This is my firebase database structure:

```
{
"posts" : {
"2017" : {
  "Nov" : {
    "19" : {
      "12:56 PM" : {
        "activities" : "jumping, rafting",
        "description" : "Hello from the other side",
        "location" : "Bucharest, Roamania",
        "privacy" : "1",
        "title" : "Making papers",
        "userID" : "cTq84vE40XhD1EprpxlQUOIwO0q2"
      }
    }
  }
}
},
```

And this is my fetching data function:

```
func fetchPosts() {
    refHandle = ref.child("posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.postList.removeAll()

            for posts in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot] {
                let postObject = posts.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let activities = postObject?["activities"]
                let description = postObject?["description"]
                let location = postObject?["location"]
                let privacy = postObject?["privacy"]
                let commentsNr = postObject?["commentsNr"]
                let likesNr = postObject?["likesNr"]
                let image = postObject?["images"]
                let title = postObject?["title"]
                let name = postObject?["name"]
                let date = postObject?["date"]

                let post = Post(title: title as? String, name: name as? String, image: image as? UIImage, info: description as? String, likesNr: likesNr as? Int, privacy: privacy as? Int, location: location as? String, commentsNr: commentsNr as? Int, activities: activities as? String, date: date as? String)

                print("A~ \(activities) / \(location)")

                self.postList.append(post)
            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

What have I've done wrong? Should I rethink the firebase database structure, making it easy to access within the program, or should I try a different algorithm for fetching data?

Comment: `postObject` is equal to what exactly? I think that you are missing levels in your dictionary. In your sample, It's missing `postObject["2017"] as [String:AnyObject]` for instance, and the "Nov", the "19" and the time one.

Comment: I believe the real problem is the database structure, I need to find a better way to write the data and an easier way to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to get as a dictionnary, **did you print what your snapshot contains ?**

For me, your snapshot starts at your `posts` node. Then, as you choose a value observer, your snapshot will contain only `posts` as a key and all children values.

If you want to keep your database structure like this, you need to deep down on your node level to query the informations you want. In this examples, a query that should work could be :

```
refHandle = ref.child("posts").child("2017").child("Nov").child("19").child("12:56 PM").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in //etc
```

But I recommend you to change you database structure because if you have read the Firebase documentation about how structure your database, you **must avoid nested data**. You need to flatten your database structure to have the lowest level of nodes. Like 1 level or 2 max : [Structure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

Update : If you have a well structured Firebase database, then, it will be easier for you to access your data. For me to separate in different nodes the time of the post, it's wrong. Make just a timestamp as an attribute for the post. You can start with a structure like this :

```
posts
 |-idPost
  |-idUser
  |-activities
  |-postDate
  |-etc...All the attributes for a post
```

Comment: Is there a pattern, an easy way to access, to loop through the posts of multiple users?

Comment: Great! Is there a way to access every post without specifying the child(idPost) for every one? Sorry if it's a stupid question but I'm a new to Swift. I see there is a func childByautoid, using it is the right approach?

Comment: Well in a certain way you need to uniquely identify each post right ? So you need a unique identifier. Yes using the func childByautoid is the right approach since it will generate for you a unique identifier.

Comment: If it will help you, can you upvote or validate my answer ?

Comment: Before changing my database structure, I've tried refHandle = ref.child("posts").child("2017").child("Nov").child("19").child("12:56 PM").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) and the value returned is still nil

Comment: And you keep your for loop ? Print your snapshot on your console log.